# missing required keys: [:like_id]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't get a like system working for my Rails discussion forum:

```
class Like < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :comment
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments
  has_many :likes, through: :comments
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :likes
end
```

**routes.rb:**

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments do
    resources :likes do
      put "/create", to: "likes#create"
    end
  end
end
```

**likes_controller.rb:**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    @like = Like.find(params[:like_id])
    @user = current_user.id

    Like.create(like_id: @like, post_id: @post, comment_id: @comment, user_id: @user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
    end
  end
end
```

**rake routes:**

```
post_comment_like_create PUT    /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/likes/:like_id/create(.:format) likes#create
      post_comment_likes GET    /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/likes(.:format)                 likes#index
                         POST   /posts/:post_id/comments/:comment_id/likes(.:format)                 likes#create
etc
```

---

The problem I keep running into is that it's missing like_id:

```
No route matches {:action=>"create", :comment_id=>"218", :controller=>"likes", :like_id=>nil, :post_id=>"30"} missing required keys: [:like_id]
```

What am I doing wrong? I assume most of the code is correct, as the only error it's giving me is a missing ID, I just don't understand how or where to fetch that like_id.

**EDIT:**

This is the action I'm trying to use:

```
= link_to post_comment_like_create_path(@post, comment, @like)
```

Comment: What url did you use to request this route? and what type? PUT?

Comment: Ah sorry, see my edit. I'm trying to use `= link_to post_comment_like_create_path(@post, comment, @like)`

Comment: When you are creating a new like why do you need an id in create ?

Comment: No idea, I'm quite new at this so wouldn't know why it's asking for an ID, or if it's possible to skip it.

Comment: So that you need to check if @like object exist.

Comment: I don't know what that means?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is partly in your routes, partly in your controller and partly in the view.

By using the line `resources :likes`, you are creating routes for the 7 CRUD actions automatically. This means you do not need to manually declare a `create` action in your routes (which should be a POST rather than PUT). I'd suggest reading the [Rails Guide on Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default).

In your controller, you are attempting to create an object called `@like` by finding a `Like` based on an ID. But you are creating this for the first time, so there is nothing to find.

In your view, you shouldn't be using a `link_to` for anything that affects the database but rather a `button_to` and the path you are using is also part of the problem.

Make the following changes:

**routes.rb**

```
resources :posts do
  resources :comments do
    resources :likes
  end
end
```

**likes_controller.rb**

```
class LikesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.find(params[:comment_id])
    @user = current_user.id

    Like.create(post_id: @post, comment_id: @comment, user_id: @user)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post) }
    end
  end
end
```

**view**

```
= button_to post_comment_likes_path(@post, comment)
```

I would suggest you look at the guides around nesting of routes. Nesting this deep can easily become cumbersome.

Comment: Would you suggest not nesting at all, i.e: having like be a top level route (outside of posts and comments)?

Comment: For a `like` which is only really going to ping a create or delete action and is not something anyone will be particularly interested in visiting as a resource of its own, yes I would.

Comment: Interesting, I implemented your suggestions and I'm not getting an error anymore, which is a good sign! However, no like is being created when the button is clicked. I have a `= comment.likes.count` showing 0, and doing a `Like.last` in the console only shows the last one I created manually for testing.

Comment: As a follow up: if I `destroy_all` Likes, refresh browser, click a Like button and then do `Like.last` in the console, a Like _is_ being created, but only once (if I click another Like button nothing is created), and it's missing comment_id and post_id.

Comment: Can you post your log file for when you click the like button.